# string extraction and manipulation in R with stringr / dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

Using the TTR package for getting the following data and taking out the duplicates:

```
library("TTR")
library("dplyr")
Nasdaq <- stockSymbols(exchange = "NASDAQ") %>% distinct(Name)
```

now the MarketCap column has the size in character form which I would like to transform to the appropriate numeric value. Below the first step of extracting the numeric value from the string

```
library("stringr")
Nasdaq_test  <- Nasdaq %>% 
mutate(MC=as.numeric(str_extract(MarketCap,"\\d+\\.*\\d*")))
```

But now comes the "tricky" part. The M and B need to be replaced with the numeric equivalents. This is possible but I'm using at least 4 mutate steps. That does not seem right. Any alternative routes?

Comment: `mutate(MC=as.numeric(str_extract(MarketCap,"\\d+(\\.\\d+)?"))) `

Comment: Avinash, could you elaborate a bit please? I tested both versions in R and compared using all.equal(), which returned TRUE. So what is the difference?

Comment: your regex should match `78....89`

Comment: Ok, will look into this. But the above points do not solve the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert `MarketCap` to numeric values, you might try

```
library("TTR")
library("dplyr")
Nasdaq <- stockSymbols(exchange = "NASDAQ") %>% distinct(Name)
library(stringr)

Nasdaq_Test <- Nasdaq %>% mutate(billion = grepl("B$",MarketCap), 
                        MC = as.numeric(str_replace_all(MarketCap, "[^0-9\\.]*", ""))*ifelse(billion, 1000, 1))
```

The results are in $M.  This version is a bit more concise than my original post and eliminates the warning messages about NA values.

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a look at the results.